# Parent site breaks design on iframed site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I just made a leaflet map, designed map popups with bootstrap and when i iframe my map in my wordpress site, the map popup breaks. I figure out its because my Wordpress use a little bit older bootstrap version what conflict some how with my maps design. 
I think what breaks the popup design is this element in my wordpress page.php file

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
```

Because if I delete it then map works as it should but wordpress page style is broken.

my iframe code:

```
<iframe src="link to map" width="100%" height="680" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is the style on popup. Sorry I know its messy because I used it in javascript file. +a[5]+ are javascript array variables.

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-7'>
      <div class='text-center'>
        <h5 class='card-title text-center'>"+a[2]+"</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>"+a[4]+"</p>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class='adrese'>
        <img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/map-markers-1/512/residence-512.png' width='20'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope card-text font-weight-bold'>"+a[7]+"    &nbsp </span>
        <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-1/57/basic1-011_calendar-512.png' width='20'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope card-text font-weight-bold'>"+a[8]+"</span>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5 float-right'>
      <div class='atstarpe'>
         <a href='./images/"+a[5]+".JPG' target='_blank'>
           <img class='d-block ' width='130' height='87' src='./images/"+a[5]+".JPG' alt='Pirmais slaids'>
         </a>  
      </div>
      <div class='atstarpe'>
        <a href='./images/"+a[6]+".JPG' target='_blank'>
          <img class='d-block'  width='130' 'height='87' src='./images/"+a[6]+".JPG' alt='Pirmais slaids'>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My maps popup (not iframed) 
[Not iframed map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4XYd.png)

Maps popup when iframed in Wordpress
[Iframed map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjznV.png)

Comment: CSS on parent site do not affect style inside the iframe. My guess would be that the iframe width is affecting the render. Would require more code to be sure. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Comment: I tested and you are right its render problem. But this is wierd, because if I want a good working popup i need to make iframe go out of page container